# Permutations of list of list of lists

Tags: python

I want to find the permutation of list of list of lists
For example: 
my input

```
x = [[[1,2,3],[5,6,7]],[[8,9,10],[11,12]]]
```

Required output should be:

```
[[[1,2,3],[8,9,10]],[[1,2,3],[11,12]],[[5,6,7],[8,9,10]],[[5,6,7],[11,12]]]
```

As you can see I want the innermost list to be intact and need to have that considered as an element and then do combinations.

I tried permutations(array) in itertools. But it didn't work.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: How does it "not work"? It didn't work is not an adequate problem specification.

Comment: Hint: you aren't looking for permutations, you want the *Cartesian product*

Comment: BTW don't conflate arrays with lists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need itertools.product

```
import itertools

x = [[[1,2,3],[5,6,7]],[[8,9,10],[11,12]]]
for combo in itertools.product(*x):
    print combo
```

Output:

```
([1, 2, 3], [8, 9, 10])
([1, 2, 3], [11, 12])
([5, 6, 7], [8, 9, 10])
([5, 6, 7], [11, 12])
```